# Customer VS persistent/customer templates

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, template, bug, persistent

I want to know exactly what is the difference between templates located in `customer` and `persistent/customer` and why Magento created the two ?

**Exemple :**

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml`

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

If I have to modify the `register.phtml` for exemple or `login.phtml`, I have to take the first one or the second ? In my case it was the second since always but I want to have an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

> If you diff the normal login/register templates with the persistent ones you will hopefully see some differences that affect the login/registration of users. – Ben Crook

Ben crook is right, but there seems to be a bug in Magento that causes **always** using files from `persistent/customer` - even when persistant cart is disabled.

When Magento merges all layout XML files `base/default/layout/persistent.xml` sets the template for some customer/checkout pages to `persistent/customer`, but this **should** only happen when persistant cart is enabled. **To fix** this  add `ifconfig="persistent/options/enabled"` to `<action method="setTemplate">`

**base/default/layout/persistent.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_login>
        <reference name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/customer/form/login.phtml</template></action>
            ...
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/customer/form/register.phtml</template></action>
            ...
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.login">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml</template></action>
            ...
        </reference>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml</template></action>
            ...
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
    ...
</layout>
```

<sup>From [Bug: when persistence checkout turned off; then persistent/customer/form/login.phtml still being used](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/282)</sup>

Comment: This is not at all my question and I know very well this, please delete this answer to not downvote it

Comment: @Prince Then please make clear what you ask. Title says `customer` vs `persistant/customer` template? And this answers you why you should use `persistant` at the moment. If this is known, why ask?

Comment: I never asked this problem, Is this my question : `when persistence checkout turned off; then persistent/customer/form/login.phtml still being used` ? You answer me for a problem that I don't need. And as I have said i don't wont to downvote, flag you

Comment: __Q:__ _I have to take the first one or the second ? In my case it was the second since always but I want to have an explanation._ __A:__ Its the second since always because its kind of bug - that i've tried to explain ...

Comment: @Prince updated answer to make it more clear. Hope this answers WHY you always have to edit files in `persistent/customer` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ones inside persistent sound to be related to the functionality of keeping track of unpurchased items in the cart.

> A persistent shopping cart keeps track of unpurchased items which are left in the cart, and saves the information for the customer's next visit. Customers who are “remembered” can have the contents of their shopping carts restored the next time they visit your store.

[Source](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-persistent.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time but is not my question, you are talking about `cart` instead my question was about `register and login` !

Comment: @Prince It's the same thing just for a different area of the site, it's still related to logging in for the persistent cart functionality. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600446/whats-the-meaning-of-the-persistent-directory-in-magento-themes

Comment: If you diff the normal login/register templates with the persistent ones you will hopefully see some differences that affect the login/registration of users.

Comment: The links that you have just sent me is not interesting ! there is not even one validate answer !

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want then, I've explained what the difference is between persistent and standard templates. As for which one you use depends on whether you're using the persistent cart functionality or not.